# calling clear() in beforeAll misbehaves with protractor 2.0

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor, jasmine2.0

I've upgraded from protractor 1.8 to protractor 2.0.  I'm seeing strange behavior when using beforeAll (jasmine 2.0) to log into my app before executing test scenarios in the it blocks. It seems that the first call to element.clear() is happening last.  I am seeing this happen:

1. "teacher01" is typed into usernameFld
2. institutionFld is cleared
3. "school01" is typed into institutionFld
4. passwordFld is cleared
5. "teacherpassword" is typed into passwordFld
6. usernameFld is cleared
7. loginBtn is clicked
8. Test fails because usernameFld is blank

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong (See code below)?

**Notes:**

I've tried switching to directConnect. I've tried breaking out the clear() and sendKeys() onto separate lines.  Neither seemed to help.

Using the same code and rolling back to protractor 1.8.0, I don't have this problem. usernameFld is cleared first, then the username is typed into usernameFld and the test is able to log in fine.  Moving the login code from beforeAll into the "it" block makes the test behave as expected, too.

Note that passwordFld is an input of type password and loginBtn is just a button.  This is a test for a non-angular webpage. I'm using jasmine 2.0, chrome browser 41.0.2272.101, firefox 36.0.4 and starting the selenium server from the test script.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="teacherUsername" size="20" value="" tabindex="1" id="username" title="Enter your Username">
<input type="text" name="teacherInstitution" size="20" value="" tabindex="2" id="institution" title="Enter your Institution">
<input type="password" name="teacherPassword" size="20" tabindex="3" id="password" title="Enter your Password">
<button class="submit" tabindex="4" id="loginbtn">Log In</button>
```

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  specs: ['school_spec.js']
};
```

TEST:

```
describe('Protractor 2.0', function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  var loginBtn = element(by.id('loginbtn'));
  var usernameFld = element(by.id('username'));
  var institutionFld = element(by.id('institution'));
  var passwordFld = element(by.id('password'));

  beforeAll(function() {
    browser.get('http://mypage.net/login.html');
    usernameFld.clear().sendKeys('teacher01');
    institutionFld.clear().sendKeys('school01');
    passwordFld.clear().sendKeys('teacherpassword');
    loginBtn.click();
  });

  it('should work with beforeAll', function() {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My Classes');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't provide you an explanation, but, hopefully, a solution.

Move the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` to `beforeAll()` and call `sendKeys()` only then `clear()` is completed:

```
beforeAll(function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('http://mypage.net/login.html');

    usernameFld.clear().then(function () {
        usernameFld.sendKeys('teacher01');
    });
    institutionFld.clear().then(function () {
        institutionFld.sendKeys('school01');
    });
    passwordFld.clear().then(function () {
        passwordFld.sendKeys('teacherpassword');
    });

    loginBtn.click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @alexce, that worked!

Is this is a bug or expected behavior in protractor 2.0 (and thus the new ControlFlow in webdriverjs 2.45.1?)

I don't grok why element1.clear().sendKeys() no longer works in protractor 2.0.0 (or calling element1.clear() then element1.sendKeys() separately).  I thought clear() would still return the ElementFinder since clear() is an action and then I'd be able to call sendKeys() on that ElementFinder.  When calling element1.clear() then element1.sendKeys(), the new ControlFlow in webdriverjs 2.45.1 should ensure that they are executed in the correct order, right?

Comment: @jwall500 these are good questions and I'm not sure if this is a bug in the control flow at the moment. Could you verify that the solution I've provided makes any difference? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce Your solution worked for my simple example.  The fields are cleared and populated in the right order, allowing the test to log in from the beforeAll block.  Now trying to get it to work with our PageObjects that we require in the onPrepare section of conf.js.

Comment: @jwall500 speaking about the initial problem, if I were you, I'd create an issue at protractor github tracker providing a reproduceable example - and please reference this thread in the issue so that a workaround will be also provided. Thank you!

Comment: Just to follow-up, I was unable to reproduce the example that was posted in the protractor issues, so I've closed that. I'd be happy to take a look at another issue if an example that is truly reproducible is included.

Comment: @Jmr okay, thanks for the update. I am not sure why this kind of workaround works. Probably this is application implementation-specific..

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!  I will try reproducing this with a siimple html page and try not to use require-all